# Spearmans correlations on a subset of my data

Tags: r

I am trying to perform spearmans correlations on a subset of my data, but each time I am getting the same p value and rho as when I conduct the test on my entire dataset.

This is the code for the test on my entire data set
cor.test(analytic_data_survey$mvd_score, analytic_data_survey$total_jealousy_score,
method = "spearman")

this is the output:
S = 209441, p-value = 0.06342
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
rho
0.1736731

This is the code for the test I am trying to do on a subset of my data (females):
cor.test(analytic_data_survey$mvd_score, analytic_data_survey$total_jealousy_score,
subset = sex == "Female",
method = "spearman")

and you can see the output is the same:
S = 209441, p-value = 0.06342
alternative hypothesis: true rho is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
rho
0.1736731

I am fairly new to R so I'm unsure if there is another way to conduct this test on a subset of my dataset. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are mixing forms of `cor.test()`. See the manual page at `?cor.test`. Try `cor.test(total_jealousy_score~mvd_score, analytic_data_survey, subset=sex == "Female, method="spearman")`. If that does not work, you will need to provide a sample of your data using `dput()`.

Comment: when I use this, I get an error that the formula is invalid/missing

Comment: Read the last sentence of my comment.

Comment: I had a typo in my original comment which you may have corrected. It should be `cor.test(total_jealousy_score~mvd_score, analytic_data_survey, subset=sex == "Female", method="spearman")` with "Female" in quotes.